# SpanGroupIndex and SpanIndex Recycler View

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, gridlayoutmanager

I was looking at the documentation of GridLayoutManager and its SpanSizeLookUp Class for RecyclerView. But I cant get to know about the getSpanGroupIndex and getSpanIndex methods of the SpanSizeLookUp Class. I also experimented by overriding and returning arbitary number(less than span count). But I cant get to know what is it used for.

I am not able to understand the Documentation instructions. I would like to clear this.

Comment: You are referring to [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup.html) page right?

SpanSizeLookup is used if you want to have items that take more than one column (if vertical) or row (if horizontal).

Can you be more specific about which methods are not obvious so I can fix them ?

Comment: I just cant understand both methods.

Answer (score 10):

By default, each item in a grid layout takes 1 span. If Grid is horizontal, span means a row and if Grid is vertical, span means a column. If your items may need to layout themselves into multiple spans (e.g. a header item in a 3 column grid would have spanSize=3), you can provide a SpanSizeLookup which returns 3 if item is a header item and 1 if it is a regular item.

When GridLayoutManager (GLM) needs to decide the span for an item, it calls getSpanIndex in SpanSizeLookup. That method traverses every item before the given position to decide which span this item should be placed at.

For example, if you call `glm.scrollToPosition(n)`, SpanSizeLookup goes through every item from 0  to N, checks how many spans each of them consume and decide where the item at `N` would be positioned. Lets say you have a grid w/ a header row at index 0 and 3, and rest of the items take 1 span. If GLM calls `spanSizeLookup.getSpanIndex(4)` it will call `getSpanIndex` for `0 1 2 3`, realize that after 3rd item, next item should be placed at span 0 and return it.

Although it caches these results, it is inefficient to traverse all items if you can calculate it faster. For instance, maybe you know that all items take 1 span, then you can override `getSpanIndex` and return `n % spanCount` . This is why that method is public.

`getSpanGroupIndex` is the group of the item. If GLM is vertical, group is "row" and if GLM is horizontal, group is "column". It is used mainly for accessibility. For the example above where each item consumes 1 span, you can override this method and return `n / spanCount`. I agree that this method is not clear, will create a ticket to improve documentation.

Comment: Thanks. Even with current documentation on dev.android.com I had to additionally read this explanation of yours to start to understand. Main points which were unclear: 1. what is 'index'? index in what? (answer: index in span group) 2. would be helpful to explicitly mention that span = column for vertical and span = row for horizontal 3. explicitly mention that span group is row for vertical and column for horizontal

Comment: i did not find this explanation in the documentation. just wanted to thank you for writing this. i was troubleshooting for hours before i read this.